# absolute and relative div positioning

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I have created a  few divs inside divs:). The problem is that the FOOTER div is printed above the div which contains absolute divs and is not dipalyed as last (at the bottom).

I tried a few combinations for footer div like: `"position: absolute; top: 0px; left:0px"`, but it still displyed at the top of page.

How to move it to the bottom with current divs?
http://jsfiddle.net/hsbgpmus/2/

Where is the problem?

ADDED:

I want to have footer div not at the bottom of web browser window, but as last div right after div containing BBBB string.

Comment: position: absolute; bottom: 0; makes to bottom. Not sure question

Comment: Question is not clear, I don't see any relative position.

Comment: You need `position: relative` on the parent `div` in order for absolute position to work, otherwise it is positioned based on the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used **"position:static"** in your example fiddle. Static means the element will flow into the page as it normally would.

For more info. about positioning element using css refer [this link](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/).

Positioning element absolutely and setting top and left to 0px means you want to align it at the top. To align element at the bottom of the parent element, you have to set **bottom** property (not **top** property)

CSS code :

```
<footer_element_class_or_id> {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Pawel : Can you add some more details to the questions, its not clear to me. It would be helpful if you add final result, how you want the elements to be shown.

Comment: But use this one http://jsfiddle.net/hsbgpmus/4/  and modify only last (FOOTER) div to be a bit higher, after div containign BBB value:)... this maybe be not possible?

Comment: It can be aligned by modifying body height property (http://jsfiddle.net/hsbgpmus/6/). But this solutions is not reliable and preferred at all because different browsers interpret pixel values differently.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<div style="position:relative; height:600px">
<div style="width: 100px">
    <h1>HEaDER</h1>
    <div>
        <div style="position: static">
            <div style="padding: 10px; position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px; background-color: yellow;">aaaaa</div>
            <div style="padding: 10px; position: absolute; top: 200px; background-color: yellow;">cccc</div>
            <div style="padding: 10px; position: absolute; top: 300px;  background-color: yellow;">bbbb</div>
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; bottom:0">
            <h1>FOOTER</h1>
        </DIV>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/anjum121/xmox7pjq/

you need to wrapp your parent div to relative position

Answer (score 0):

use below code for footer,

```
position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left:0px
```

Comment: Sh..t... I tried with bottom and positioning absolue... strange:).. but thanks::)

Answer (score 0):

try this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/hsbgpmus/3/

```
.footer{

    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;

}
```

html

```
<div class ="footer"><h1>FOOTER</h1></DIV>
```